# Cannot install_github in R (Installation failed : name lookup timeout)

Tags: r, github, rcharts

I have R installed in a Slackware server. When I tried to install rCharts package via github, I got following error:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0T77.png)

> devtools::install_github('ramnathv/rCharts@dev')
> Downloading GitHub repo ramnathv/rCharts@dev from URL https://api.github.com/repos/ramnathv/rCharts/zipball/dev
> Installation failed: name lookup timed out

I have Rstudio running on my windows laptop as well. It worked just fine when I tried to install the rCharts package. The difference I noticed that in my laptop, it takes much time, maybe 4-5 minutes, to connect to the URL address before it begin to install the package, while in the Slackware server, it takes less than a minute trying to connect the URL address before the error message showed up.

Maybe is it related to curl? Since I have searched the "name lookup timed out" phrase, many results showed up that it is the curl problem.

Here is the devtools::session_info():

```
> devtools::session_info()
Session info ------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value
 version  R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
 system   i586, linux-gnu
 ui       X11
 language (EN)
 collate  C
 tz       <NA>
 date     2018-03-20
Packages ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 package   * version date       source
 base      * 3.3.3   2017-12-20 local
 datasets  * 3.3.3   2017-12-20 local
 devtools    1.13.5  2018-02-18 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 digest      0.6.13  2017-12-14 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 graphics  * 3.3.3   2017-12-20 local
 grDevices * 3.3.3   2017-12-20 local
 memoise     1.1.0   2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 methods   * 3.3.3   2017-12-20 local
 stats     * 3.3.3   2017-12-20 local
 utils     * 3.3.3   2017-12-20 local
 withr       2.1.1   2017-12-19 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
```

Comment: Are you behind any sort of firewall?  Normally you should not have to get manually involved with an R package download.  You may try using a different mirror.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't think there is some sort of firewall. The Slackware server and the laptop are in the same network and using the same internet connection. Moreover, I have no problem when I install R packages via CRAN in the Slackware server. In fact, the server cannot install any other packages from github repository. I am already trying to install another packages from github as well, but the error message still the same.